# json parsing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

in my javascript I have this array

```
var versions = 
[{"id":"454","name":"jack"},
{"id":"4","name":"rose"}
{"id":"6","name":"ikma"}
{"id":"5","name":"naki"}
{"id":"667","name":"dasi"}
]
```

I want to parse it for the name where id is 4. how would i do that.

Comment: You are missing some comas in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
$.each(versions, function(index, value) { 
   if (value['id'] === '4') {
        alert('got it!');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is untested, but should work.

```
for(var i in versions) {
   if(versions[i].id == 4) {
        alert(versions[i].name);
        break;
   }
}
```

*Edit*: Added short circuit.

Comment: OP asked for a solution using jQuery. I think... :-)

Comment: And what is the difference between one that uses jquery and one which does not?  Anything that is valid javascript will work with jquery, and this solution will also work without it.

Comment: sure. there is no difference. I was just pointing what the OP asked for. I guess he/she has his/her reasons.

Comment: That's understandable, I just resist writing anything that is dependent on a library if there is a just as easy and just as readable way of doing it without it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate through the array and pull out the names where the id equals "4"

```
var names = [];

for(var i=0; i<versions.length; i=i+1)
{
    var version = versions[i];
    if(version.id == "4")
    {
        names.push(version.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just noticed the title and saw that you wanted to parse it using jQuery. But this works too and doesn't require any Javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
var versions = {
  '454': {name: 'jack'},
  '4': {name: 'rose'},
  '6': {name: 'ikma'},
  '5': {name: 'naki'},
  '667': {name: 'dasi'}
};

alert(versions['4'].name);
```